# laravel .env email password not taking, throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, email, office365

I have a mail password = hello@12345 . When I'm setting up this in laravel 5.4 .env file, sending mail throwing error 554, which is credentials not matching. I know everything is right including host name, username, server, driver, encryption . Only password which has int() value after @ , not working. Is there any way to solve or bypass this . My host name is outlook.office365.com

Comment: Are you sure it is a credentials issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221416/smtp-error-554

Answer (score 0):

Set your password `.env`with `""`:

```
password="hello@12345"
```

**NOTE:** Single quotations also work.

Also, by convention, you should capitalize all your variables:

```
PASSWORD
```